# How to solve the allocation of rows to individual TestCase

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have such a problem. I am dealing here with a series of TestCase, whereby one script in the mainreader.py file will always assign one username and password, row by row. Unfortunately I don't know how to do it. Each TC when will call the mainreader should get 2 variables from a new row.
So far I only have a general call in this script, but I don't know how to do it.

manireader.py:

```
    import csv


with open ('aisg_users.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            aisg_username = row[0]
            aisg_password = row[1]
            print(aisg_username)
            print(aisg_password)
            line_count += 1
    else:
        exit()
        print("Not FOUND")
```

Did anyone solve something like this?

[image: picture of plan]

Comment: Hi, You mean CSV file consist of multiple user credential and you want to call different credential for every test case? If this is your expectation then assign unique header for every credential and based on that header fetch the credential in every test case

Comment: Yes this is my expectation.. Do you have any example?

Comment: i have added  pic in new comment pls refer

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Hashtable < String, String > getData(String testName, String sheetName, Xls_Reader xls) {
int testCaseStartIndex = 0;
for (int rNum = 1; rNum <= xls.getRowCount(sheetName); rNum++) {
    if (testName.equals(xls.getCellData(sheetName, 0, rNum))) {
        testCaseStartIndex = rNum;
        break;
    }
}

int colStartIndex = testCaseStartIndex + 1;
int cols = 1;
while (!xls.getCellData(sheetName, cols, colStartIndex).equals("")) {
    cols++;
}

int dataStartIndex = testCaseStartIndex + 2;
int rows = 0;
while (!xls.getCellData(sheetName, 1, (dataStartIndex + rows)).equals("")) {
    rows++;
}
Hashtable < String, String > table = null;
for (int rNum = dataStartIndex; rNum < (dataStartIndex + rows); rNum++) {
    table = new Hashtable < String, String > ();
    for (int cNum = 0; cNum < cols; cNum++) {
        table.put(xls.getCellData(sheetName, cNum, colStartIndex), xls.getCellData(sheetName, cNum, rNum));
    }
}
return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In below image i have given unique header name for every credential so in my custom function  i will pass the unique headername which will identify the row number and rownumber + 1 is my user credential location.

[image]